# Android Studio layout design view shows overlay after upgrade to v3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

After upgrading to Android Studio v3.0 the design view for all my layouts look like below, i.e. ActionBarOverlayLayout covers the whole design surface, and the app does not even use the actionbar.

[image]

In the manifest the application element is:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyAppName"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And AppTheme is defined in styles.xml like

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">?attr/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/colorControlActivated</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change parent style of Apptheme

From:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

To:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I hope it will help.